# set_clip_path on a matplotlib clabel not clipping properly

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm making a contour plot that is clipped to a polygon path:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
axes = plt.subplot()
x,y = np.meshgrid( np.linspace(-10,10,51), np.linspace(-10,10,51) ) 
z = np.sin(np.sqrt(x**2+y**2))
CS =  axes.contour(x, y, z, np.linspace(-1,1,11) )
axes.set_aspect('equal')

# clip contours by polygon
radius = 8
t = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,101)
x_bound,y_bound = radius*np.sin(t),radius*(np.cos(t)+0.1*(np.cos(7*t)))
clip_map = Polygon(list(zip(x_bound,y_bound)),fc='#EEEEEE',ec='none')
axes.add_patch(clip_map)
for collection in CS.collections:
    collection.set_clip_path(clip_map)

# label the contours    
CLB = axes.clabel(CS, colors='black')
for text_object in CLB:
    text_object.set_clip_path(clip_map) # Doesn't do anything!

plt.show()
```

To my surprise, the labels aren't clipped despite the `Text` objects having a `set_clip_path` method that doesn't return an error:

[image: contour plot where labels aren't clipped]

How can I clip the labels outside of the gray polygon area? Do I need to resort to manually finding the X and Y positions, calculating point in polygon, and `set_visible = False` for each `Text` item? Why doesn't this code work as-is? I'm using matplotlib version 1.5.1 and python 3.5.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just in case someone comes across the same issue someday, here's a solution that resorts to having to use the `shapely` package to test for point in polygon to set the visibility state of the `Text` object. It gets the job done, but it would be nice if it was possible to use `set_clip_path` to work directly on the `Text` object.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import Polygon as ShapelyPolygon
from shapely.geometry import Point as ShapelyPoint

fig = plt.figure()
axes = plt.subplot()
x,y = np.meshgrid( np.linspace(-10,10,51), np.linspace(-10,10,51) ) 
z = np.sin(np.sqrt(x**2+y**2))
CS =  axes.contour(x, y, z, np.linspace(-1,1,11) )
axes.set_aspect('equal')

# clip contours by polygon
radius = 8
t = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,101)
x_bound,y_bound = radius*np.sin(t),radius*(np.cos(t)+0.1*(np.cos(7*t)))
clip_map = Polygon(list(zip(x_bound,y_bound)),fc='#EEEEEE',ec='none')
axes.add_patch(clip_map)
for collection in CS.collections:
    collection.set_clip_path(clip_map)

# label the contours    
CLB = axes.clabel(CS, colors='black')
clip_map_shapely = ShapelyPolygon(clip_map.get_xy())

for text_object in CLB:
    if not clip_map_shapely.contains(ShapelyPoint(text_object.get_position())):
        text_object.set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the bounty set to the question has not helped to obtain an answer which uses clipping, so I will award it to this workaround-answer.